# Problem with receiving data from jsp to servlet

Tags: java, javascript, json, servlets

I have problem with receive data from jsp to servlet.
I know that I must serializes this data using JSON.
In my jsp in JavaScript I make something like this:

```
var myJSONText = JSON.stringify(items);
document.getElementById('test').value = myJSONText;
```

where, items is an array of JavaScript objects, and test:

```
<input type="hidden" name="test" id="test">
```

Now I want to receive this array on the servlet, I'm trying that (in method doPost()):

```
request.getParameter("test");
```

but it contains an empty value. Has anyone idea how to do it?

Comment: "It doesn't work" is too vague. Does the parameter not exist? Is it returning null? Does it explode your keyboard into a brilliant fireball?

Comment: Yes this form method is post.

Comment: It means that I receive empty object

Comment: Does it ever hit the servlet?

Comment: when do you call `document.getElementById('test').value = myJSONText;`. You need to call this before form post. Did you do so?

Comment: and if you did call the javascript section before. What is the value of myJsonText

Comment: before post ensure that `alert(test)`

Comment: @Ravi Parekh it would be better to alert(myJsonText) to make sure their is a value in there.

Comment: @RMT we are just giving hint to @Pinio if he could do primarily. :)

Answer (score 0):

Can you show your code, when you do post request to server? Seems it should be something like

```
$.post('http:myurl.com', data)
```

or

```
<form ...>
<input type="submit">
</form>
```